# data.table aggregate with multiple conditions in BY statement

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

Here's some play data

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                food = c("bacon","bacon","bacon","bacon","bacon","cheese","sausage","avocado","ham"),
                enjoyment = c(20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20))
```

resulting in

```
 ID    food enjoyment
1  1   bacon        20
2  1   bacon        20
3  1   bacon        20
4  2   bacon        20
5  2   bacon        20
6  2  cheese        20
7  2 sausage        20
8  3 avocado        20
9  3     ham        20
```

What I would like to do is, for each person (ID), sum their enjoyment for bacon and cheese only

My code so far is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,id_enjoyment_sum := sum(enjoyment), by =.(ID,food == "bacon"|food == "cheese")]
```

which results in

```
 ID    food enjoyment id_enjoyment_sum
1:  1   bacon        20               60
2:  1   bacon        20               60
3:  1   bacon        20               60
4:  2   bacon        20               60
5:  2   bacon        20               60
6:  2  cheese        20               60
7:  2 sausage        20               20
8:  3 avocado        20               40
9:  3     ham        20               40
```

This has done what I want it to do, but it's also summed for each person, their enjoyment of non bacon and non cheese food. Notice that ID 3 does not eat bacon or cheese but my code has still summed his enjoyment for what he does eat.

IDEALLY, the code should result in

```
ID    food enjoyment id_enjoyment_sum
1:  1   bacon        20               60
2:  1   bacon        20               60
3:  1   bacon        20               60
4:  2   bacon        20               60
5:  2   bacon        20               60
6:  2  cheese        20               60
7:  2 sausage        20               60
8:  3 avocado        20               0
9:  3     ham        20               0
```

So my question is, how do I set up the BY clause to sum, for each id, only the enjoyment of bacon and cheese?

Comment: I think you want `df[food %in% c("bacon", "cheese"), s := sum(enjoyment), by=ID]` I'd recommend going through the vignettes, which clarify the typical syntax patterns: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: `df[, s := sum(enjoyment[food %in% c("bacon", "cheese")]), by=ID]` computes expected results

Comment: Thank you both, HubertL's solution worked on my real data, for some reason Frank's resulted in the same result as my original solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a one liner I would do this:

```
df[,
    id_enjoyment_sum := sum(
        ifelse(food %in% c("bacon", "cheese"), enjoyment, 0)
    )
    , by =.(ID)]
```

If overwriting the enjoyment column is not a problem, you could consider this:

```
df[! food %in% c("bacon", "cheese"), enjoyment := 0]
df[, id_enjoyment_sum := sum(enjoyment), by = .(ID)]
```

When you group by multiple variables there will be groups for each combination and the aggregation will happen within these groups. So in your case there is a group of rows for

1. `ID == 1 and (food == "bacon"|food == "cheese") == TRUE`,
2. `ID == 2 and (food == "bacon"|food == "cheese") == TRUE`,
3. `ID == 2 and (food == "bacon"|food == "cheese") == FALSE` and so on.